# width for <td> in GMail has no effect

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, gmail, html-email

I have a design for HTML emails which must display like

---

|  image'a'here<<<<<<<<<<<**space**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>image'b'here  |

---

```
<table class="wrapper">
<tr>
    <td class="header" style="padding: 15px 15px 0;">

        <table class="max-width" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>

                <!--RB logo-->
                **<td  style="width: 93% !important;vertical-align: top;">**
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a class="link-style" href="https://www.reportbee.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0135a40176b33deb024da1fea/images/d86f927a-3eef-4e8f-9dae-99753e62b0b5.png" alt="Report Bee" title="Report Bee"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <!--RB flag-->
                <td>
                    <table class="block" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td> <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/0135a40176b33deb024da1fea/images/2cddc1b3-1e85-4759-8cb1-7e07e9a2d89c.png" alt=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried to specify width for the  which contains my first image. But Gmail doesnot accept the width for  and it displays my email as

---

|   image'a'here image'b'here                 |

---

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For what reason you are trying to add width for the second tables first `td`

Comment: that td is what containing my image'a'.

Comment: as Gmail does not accept float property for image Im trying to specify width for the first td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want two images to sit at opposite ends of an email, I use:

```
<td width="40" align="left"><img></td>

<td width="100%"><img></td>

<td width="40" align="right"><img></td>
```

As both images have fixed widths, the spacer in the centre that is 100% pushes the images to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sending html email just pass following info in header

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Main things is content type:  `**Content-type:text/html**`

pass content type text/html for html email

Answer (score 0):

i have experienced a problem like this before.. after doing a lot of research online, i came to know style tag and any most of the css elements will not work in gmail and outlook

so if you are giving a width for td please make it like **td width=" "** then you can see the effect